# using Restful API in setup and teardown functions (Selenium)

Tags: rest, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is a question that was asked in an interview - How can I use a company's Restful API in `setup()` and `teardown()` functions to decrease the run-time of the test-case or increase the performance of the test code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please update your question with the code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RestFul API to create a user in the setup function (of Course if the API allows to do that). This will speed up your test case since you wouldn't have to use the webelements to sign up. You can delete this user in your tearDown function at the end of you test case.